# How can I install man pages from FreeBSD server via console command?

Tags: command-line-interface, installation, freebsd, man

How can I install man pages from FreeBSD server via console command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount FreeBSD cdrom:

```
mount /cdrom
```

and run manpages install scripts(change 8.2 to your version):

```
/cdrom/8.2-RELEASE/manpages/install.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to run `sysinstall`, select Configure, Distributions, check the man pages, when you select Exit it will prompt you for where you want to install from.

Otherwise you can download the man tar files and extract them manually, but that's not nearly as easy.